Circuit quantization procedure
In circuit QED, we construct the hamiltonian of a circuit following Devoret's procedure.
We start from a classical treatment, in which we impose Kirchhoff's voltage laws on fundamental loops and construct the lagrangian in such a way that it returns Kirchhoff's current laws on independent nodes as equations of motion. Once the lagrangian has been constructed, we can move on to the hamiltonian and then quantize the system.
Therefore, the first step is to build the classical theory, and then quantize it (as it is done for the LC circuit, for example).
However, is there a classical theory, if there is a Josephson junction in the circuit? Is it correct to start with a classical treatment, if there is a junction in the circuit, as if it were a classical circuit element, or is it a formal extension of the procedure?
Typically, we do this way even in this case. Now, does the classical lagrangian, that we obtain in such a case, describe a real classical system, at least in some regime, that we want to quantize? Shouldn't current and phase be operators? Is there a regime in which all Kirchhoff's laws hold classically, that justify the first step of the procedure even in this case?

cross-posted on https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/39066/55

Josephson junction can be considered classically in the regime when quantum fluctuations of the superconductor phase are small. In this case, it is simply a circuit element with a phase-current relation
$$
I = I_c\sin\Delta\phi,
$$
where $\Delta\phi$ is the phase difference between the edges of the junction. Adding phase-voltage relations
$$
V_i = \frac{\hbar}{2e} \frac{d\phi_i}{dt}
$$
and using equations for other circuit elements, we are able to derive the classical equations for the phases $\phi_i$ (where the index $i$ enumerates the nodes of the circuit). So, to answer the question, it is perfectly OK to treat the circuit classically in the presence of the junction. The main effect of the Josephson junction is that it introduces nonlinearity into the circuit.
As an example, let us consider the following circuit (describing a charge qubit at zero voltage):

Here the phase $\phi$ is the only dynamical variable. Using the equations above and the relation $I = \frac{dQ}{dt} = C\frac{dV}{dt}$, we get the equation of motion
$$
\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2} = -\frac{2eI_c}{\hbar C} \sin\phi.
$$
It is an apparantly nonlinear equation of the physical pendulum. Of course, it can also be obtained from the Lagrangian constructed using Devoret procedure:
$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{\hbar^2}{2E_c} \left( \frac{d\phi}{dt}\right)^2 + E_J\cos{\phi}
$$
(here $E_c = \frac{2e^2}{C}$ is the charging energy and $E_J = \frac{\hbar I_c}{2e}$ is the Josephson energy.)
To discuss at which circumstances we can use the classical equations of motion instead of full quantum treatment, we should consider the problem quantum-mechanically and check the applicability of the quasiclassical approximation. I will probably edit the post later to add more detail on this, but now I will just state that the quasiclassical limit here requires $E_J \gg E_c$. Physically this means that the Josephson potential is sufficiently deep, so quantum fluctuations can't "smear" the phase variable over the whole range $[-\pi, \pi]$, and it is either confined near $\phi = 0$ or follows some well-defined quasiclassical trajectory.

For a voltage biased Cooper pair box, the condition $E_J \gg E_c$ corresponds to the transmon regime, in which the system becomes insensitive to the gate noise. In this regime, we obtain the hamiltonian of a Duffing oscillator and the system acts as an artificial atom. If this condition corresponds also to semiclassical regime, in which the phase is essentially classical, why, in the description of the transmon regime, do we continue to treat the system quantumly?

If we are talking about lowest-energy levels, we need quantum description even in the transmon regime. The states corresponding to them are localized near the potential minimum, which also somehow agree with classical intuition. For higher energies, we get quasiclassical wavefunctions. However, strictly saying, being in quasiclassical regime is not enough to treat the quantum system fully classically. You should either construct a wave packet or introduce dissipation in the system. Without that, a pure quantum system isolated from the environment should always be described by a wavefunction.

The starting point in the study of a QED circuit is the derivation of its hamiltonian and the standard procedure for obtaining the hamiltonian is that of Devoret, which starts by obtaining the classical lagrangian of the circuit, in which all circuit elements are treated classically,  which is constructed in such a way that all Kirchhoff's laws hold.
We do this way everytime: for example, we use this procedure to derive the lagrangian of a voltage biased CPB, independently of its regime, for every possible choice of $E_J$ and $E_c$,
How can we justify this procedure in general?

That's a difficult question for me. Being honest, I don't fully understand the Devoret procedure for several years. However, I have some thoughts. First, we should consider some microscopic theory for superconductivity. Then, we should obtain a low-energy effective action for the order parameter and the EM field. Finally, we should get rid of EM field degrees of freedom and express our action in terms of the order parameter phase only. Maybe more approximations are needed, but finally we will get the Devoret action.
